# Does anyone know how to use css3 to create a double curve on the header?

Tags: html, css, header, styles

I know how to use border-(bottom|top)-(left|right)-radius: XX;
is there any way to create a curve that changes direction halfway through?

Comment: You should draw it in Paint and attach the image so your intention is clear.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313593/css3-double-rounded-border-is-it-possible-without-2-divs

Answer (score 0):

What about overlaying one `<div>` on top of another like this:

[image]

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner-bottom"></div>
    <div class="inner-top"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.outer {
    position: relative;
}

div.inner-top {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ABC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}

div.inner-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: #ABC;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osozm0yc/)